# Get total number of comments from posts in a specific custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, wpdb, comments

I’m having some difficulties trying to get total number of comments from posts **within** a specific custom taxonomy.

The setup is as such: I’ve created a custom taxonomy for my posts, called “features”. Within that taxonomy I’ve like four or five terms. Then, some of my posts are put into feature-term 1, feature-term 2, etc.

I can get this to work and when making a query I can also retrieve how many posts are in each term. But then I would like to show the total number of comments that all the posts within each feature-term has. So for example, under feature-term 1, the total number of posts is 12 and the total number of comments are 34.

I’ve tried with this query:
`SELECT SUM(comment_count) AS totalcc FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = {$term->term_id} AND object_id = ID`
But it gives me an incorrect answer can I can’t quite get an overview of where I’m failing.

Maybe there is an easier way to do it, a way that Wordpress provide but if so I haven’t been able to locate that.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop through your posts, use [`get_comments_number()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) to get the number of comments for each post, and then accumulate the total number of comments in a separate variable. e.g.:

```
<?php
$features_comment_count = 0;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$features_comment_count += get_comments_number();

endwhile; endif;
?>
```

(I'll assume that you know how to custom-query your posts, and can adapt the above code as necessary.)

If you want to count the comments *before* outputting post content, then simply run the above loop, and then rewind posts using [`rewind_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts):

```
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
```

Then, you can output your posts loop as per normal.